# How to set additional required fields on back4app user object in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, parse-server, back4app

I am using parse_server_sdk in flutter mobile to signup a user in an app. Ideally, you can call the `ParseUser.createUser(username, password, email)` function to do this. My question is that I have added columns `firstname` and `lastname` to the `User` class via back4app console so my users have additional fields besides what is provided out of the box. I intend to  make these columns required which means they need to be set when a user is created in the app. The problem is I cannot find (or I am unaware of) a function within `ParseUser` that allows you to include other parameters beyond username, password and email. My current workaround is to:

- Make the columns not required
- First create the user in the app
- Then, immediately turn around and update the user object with values for the added columns
- Save the user object again in the same flow

It just seems a bit awkward to do it this way. Is there a more straightforward way to do this that I haven't considered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code should work:

```dart
final user = ParseUser.createUser(username, password, email)
  ..set('firstname', firstname)
  ..set('lastname', lastname);
await user.signUp();
```

Comment: Excellent. I didn't consider cascading on the user object prior to invoking signup. Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.